# Почему стоит тире?

Tags: запятые, тире, деепричастия

**Охраняя природу — охраняем здоровье**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Охраняя природу — охраняем здоровье***

Это рекламный лозунг, сло́ган — лаконичная, легко запоминающаяся фраза, выражающая суть рекламного сообщения.

Тире здесь **интонационное**, оно стоит на месте обычной запятой (при обособлении деепричастного оборота) и  обозначает увеличенную паузу.

По произношению, семантике и знакам препинания высказывание близко к  бессоюзному сложному предложению (БСП): *Охраняешь природу — охраняешь здоровье*. Тире обозначает взаимообусловленные отношения между частями БСП.